# after_setup_theme function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

when i call after_setup_theme directly in page without any condition it works but when i pass through if loop it does not work. we have checked & we are entering into that loop and even echo or alert gives the output inside that loop here is my simple one liner when user submits form we are passing the post variable 
 if it is like that above otherfunction it works without any issue but it loads just after plugin is activated. we want users to click & then activate this function from plugin setting page..

```
      add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'otherfunction' )
```

but if it is like this

```
    if($_POST['action'] == 'name1') {
      add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'otherfunction' );
   }
```

it does not work. we used var_dump to check $_POST['action'] value and its name1 only then echoed inside that if loop it gives output but dont know why add_action does not work.

Comment: you mean you are using ajax call ? and you add_action dynamically ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes ..............

Comment: like you are doing it's impossible to call add_action dynamicly you need to do it in another way, am gonna put my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot do it this way, as when you add and action, there is the function **do_action** that is activate, so a solution can be to always call your add_action() and when the user submit the form you call the function do_action() to activate it.

if you are doing this in the front-end of your site you may do something like that in your plugin :

```
function otherfunction() {
    do_action('after_setup_theme', .... );
    }

add_action("wp_ajax_name1", "otherfunction");

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_name1", "otherfunction");
```

Hope this helps.